# Download csv file from Backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to create a csv file and insert my data and download it from the browser. I am creating the csv file in the express js Backend and send the link to react js frontend to download through browser.

I am using fast csv plugin to write the data into csv. Here is my code.

```
async function dataToCSV(data) {
    var fileName = "report.csv";
    var ws = await fileSystem.createWriteStream('../' + fileName);
    var csv;
    await fastcsv.write(data, { headers: true }).on("finish", function () {
        console.log(ws);
        csv = "<a href='../report.csv' download='report.csv' id='download-link'></a>";
    }).pipe(ws);
    return csv;
}
```

After getting the output from this method, I am sending this to the front end.

```
return dataToCSV(jsonData).then((response) => {
            return {
                headers,
                statusCode: 200,
                body: response,
                type: 'binary'
            };
        }).catch((e) => {
            return {
                headers,
                statusCode: 400,
                body: {
                    error: e.message
                }
            };
        })
```

Front end get the response as given below.

```
<a href='report.csv' download='report.csv' id='download-link'></a>
```

Then I use following code to download it through browser using react js.

```
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.innerHTML = response.trim();
 document.body.appendChild(div);
 var downloadLink = document.getElementById('download-link');
 if (downloadLink !== null) {
     downloadLink.click();
 }
 document.body.removeChild(div);
```

File was created in the backend I can confirm. But when it is downloaded from the browser, it gets failed. There is no error in logs. Browser says

> Failed - No file

I cannot understand why it fails. I think response is sent to the frontend before file is created or it can't identify the path where the file is created. But I am not sure about it. Please help me find a solution for this.

Comment: Return from the server a anchor tag with href="..report.csv" !!!! this is incorrect, you need to return back full binary data or full file url link

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more. With a example if you can please.

Answer (score 1):

`.pipe()` does not return a Promise, so your `await` does not do what's intended. If you'd like to wait for a stream to finish using Promises, see [stream.pipeline](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback).

It is possible that additional factors are in play - for example, your HTTP handler looks nothing like an `express` handler (even though your question includes the "express" tag). If it's a serverless function (AWS Lambda?), you may need to modify your strategy; depending on the platform, functions may not be able to serve files.

In any case, it would be best to construct a CSV file and send it directly to the client, without writing to the filesystem, using streams (though it does not appear to be possible in Node on AWS Lambda). Failing that, it's always possible to stream the file to a cloud storage solution and provide the client with [a pre-signed URL](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript/).